# My university is listed on Anabin as H+ but my degree is not listed

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, germany

I already submitted my application to a MSc in Germany. Today I received an e-mail from the university telling me that they can not find my degree in the database in Anabin, so they cannot know if my degree applies to de MSc. They sent a request to the KMK (Kultusministerkonferenz), but I do not know if I should make a request, too or if there is anything else I should or can do?